# what is the preferred app for vpn remote server access?

Tags: remote

i am currently using the RDP (and RDP connection manager) app with a windows machine. trying to make sure that when i leave windows soon that i will be able to do the same thing with my ubuntu machine. thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: Ubuntu is about choice. "Preferred app"? There is no answer to this... it is a matter of opinion. OpenVPN I consider a good choice but no everyone will agree.

Comment: You could just rephrase the question. Instead of the preferred app, ask which VPN apps are available to use in Ubuntu

Comment: yes. i know linux/ubuntu, etc. is about choice. simple question. what do you prefer?

Answer (score 0):

I use Remmina Remote Desktop Client to RDP into Windows servers. It is by far the best solution I've tried, though everyone has their favorites. For VPN, I use the network-manager-openvpn-gnome package which allows me to easily work with and configure OpenVPN settings. We use a pfsense OpenVPN certificate/key setup for our VPN service however, and I'm not sure how easily transferable that is to your situation.

Comment: thank you. this is what i'm finding after some scouring of the net. i will try remmina. thank you.

Comment: to the first commenter above.. simple question. what do you prefer? don't really want to know which vpn apps are available. that is easy to determine. i want to know in simple terms, what do the users prefer? ubuntu as the platform was clear in the premise.